# I bought Alfa AWUS036NHR v2 wireless adapter but couldn't install the drive

Tags: software-installation, alfa-wireless

Yes, but I still could not install the driver that I download from the official web to the Ubuntu system
It's a source code document and I couldn't do ./configure
after I tried to use the command: make it gives me
error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Comment: sorry for my formating

Comment: I suspect that the required driver is already included in all recent Ubuntu versions. Let's identify the device first. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: So it's working fine now?

Comment: Please read my answer again: "this circa-2011 driver won’t compile in any recent Ubuntu version." The answer to how can you compile this very old driver is that you cannot.

Comment: hmmmmm.Sorry I missed that part

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Comment: Where is the accept option?

Comment: Never mind, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you tried to install a different driver because your device won’t connect. However, this circa-2011 driver won’t compile in any recent Ubuntu version.

I suspect that the required driver is already included in all recent Ubuntu versions. You can check from the terminal:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If you find that both rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu are loaded, then blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You will probably also need a change to Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70649/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-i-bought-alfa-awus036nhr-v2-wireless-adapter-bu).