# Wifi adapter Edimax EW-7811Un/Realtek RTL8188CUS on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

this wifi adapter used to work really nicely on my Ubuntu workstation when I was in 16.10 using this fixed driver : https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git

After some upgrade (probably the upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04), it stopped working, even after correcting the "random MAC address" bug in NetworkManager.conf with :

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

So I fully uninstalled the fix (now deprecated), but it's still not working.

Here is the driver now in use :

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.13.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.10.36 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

To be more precise, I can see wifi networks, I can connect to one, but then I can't reach anything. Some pingable IP from wired network are not pingable, so it's not (not only ?) about DNS conf (example : "ping 86.79.27.49").

What should I try from here ?

See comment, the "duplicate" question is not about the same adapter.

EDIT : some logs and tests.

```
$ dmesg | grep rtl
[    7.173625] usb 1-6: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[    8.130550] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[    8.159267] rtl8xxxu 1-6:1.0 wlx74da385dfd3e: renamed from wlan0
```

I can't ping 8.8.8.8 wireless with this machine on this Wifi network, but on my other machine (windows 7) connected to the same Wifi network, I can. And about name resolution, it's a step further I think, and no it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I bought Alfa AWUS036NHR v2 wireless adapter but couldn't install the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988200/i-bought-alfa-awus036nhr-v2-wireless-adapter-but-couldnt-install-the-drive)

Comment: Hi Chili, what are you saying here ? Do you think "rtl8192cu" driver would not be the best driver for my "rtl8188cus" adapter ? and I should blacklist it ? That's not what the doc is saying : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wifi_liste_carte#realtek. Or are you saying I should blacklist "rtl8xxxu" ?

Comment: Based on several cases I’ve worked on, including the duplicate, when both are loaded, blacklisting rtl8192cu is the fix. Try it; it is easily reversible if not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. So after doing the blacklist and rebooting, I have now "driver=rtl8xxxu" doing the lshw command, but I still can't do the external ping which works on wired network, and now I have a "?" instead of the small wifi icon in the top right corner (Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 17.10).

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep rtl` Or else: `iwconfig`? Can you ping with wireless? `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: I've updated the end of my question with logs and answers. I wouldn't say there are "clues".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71587/discussion-between-chili555-and-tristan).

Comment: So the issue was about conf in /etc/network/interfaces conflicting with network-manager conf, and maybe also about the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our lengthy discussions in chat, it was found that you had some settings in /etc/resolv.conf, some partial settings in /etc/network/interfaces but still relied on Network Manager to connect with wireless.

Network Manager generally is designed to completely ignore any interfaces that are declared in  /etc/network/interfaces. It is therefore preferable to use one method or the other, but not a combination of both.

I recommended that you reset both files to their defaults and rely on Network Manager entirely. You have some unique DNS nameserver settings that are required for ethernet and we also set those in Network Manager.

After making the suggested changes, detaching the ethernet cable and rebooting, the wireless is now working as expected.